# Robot Framework : Creating custom library with Run Keyword and Ignore error not working

Tags: python, robotframework

I am starting out my journey with Python as well as Robot Framework. I have stumbled upon this problem for which I am not able to reach out to a solution.

I want to create a custom library method `set_focus_and_wait_to_scroll_to_element` that takes a locator and waitime as params. The method should wait for the element to be enabled and then set focus to it. Once this is done I would like to execute javascript `arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);` for the given element locator.

Wanted to create this as a custom method because there are a bunch of places in my robot files where I was repeating this keyword so thought of wrapping it in a custom method.

While running directly through the keywords it worked fine in following fashion :

```
Run Keyword And Ignore Error          Execute Javascript           arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);        ${opportunity_stage}
```

I wanted to implement the overall logic in same way. If I am not using `Run Keyword and Ignore Error` , I am getting an error `JavascriptError: cannot read property of undefines(reading scrollintoview)`
I went through the documentation to find that Run Keywords needs to be registered before they can be used. Tried doing that but couldn't. Also the documentation mentions this to be deprecated soon. What should be the ideal solution for this ?

Implementation

**Robot File**

```
*** Settings ***
Documentation           Contains page interaction keywords for SFDC Login Page
Library                 SeleniumLibrary
Library                 ../customlibs/SupportUtils.py


*** Variables ***
${sfdc_url}                 https://test.salesforce.com
${browser_name}             chrome
${username}                 //input[@type='email']
${password}                 //input[@type='password']
${login_btn}                //input[@id='Login']



*** Keywords ***
User logs in successfully to SFDC Environment
    [Arguments]                                     ${username_value}          ${password_value}
    Open Browser                                    ${sfdc_url}                ${browser_name}
    Maximize Browser Window
    Set Focus And Wait To Scroll To Element         ${username}                30
```

Support Util Class

```
from robot.api.deco import library, keyword
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn


@library
class SupportUtils:

    def __init__(self):
        self.builtin = BuiltIn
        self.selLib = BuiltIn().get_library_instance("SeleniumLibrary")

    @keyword
    def set_focus_and_wait_to_scroll_to_element(self, locator, waitime):
        self.selLib.set_focus_to_element(locator)
        self.selLib.wait_until_element_is_enabled(locator, waitime)
        self.builtin.register_run_keyword(SeleniumLibrary, self.selLib.execute_javascript())
        self.builtin.run_keyword_and_ignore_error(self.selLib.execute_javascript('arguments[0].scrollIntoView('
                                                                                 'true);',
                                                                                 locator, ))
```